# How to add a product description on home page block?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I just wondering if it is possible to show exact product "explored" just on front page (without URL's forwarding or something like this) ?

**I.e.** User should visit my site and **immediately** see product description, without clicking on product itself.

Comment: "User should visit my site and immediately see product description" in the category page you mean ?

Comment: no, in front page. actually, i'm selling just one product and want to show it immediately expanded.

Comment: in front ok but wich page ?

Comment: home page :) afaik it also called "frontpage" :)

Comment: Yes it is possible, just find a programmer who has some knowledge with Magento and you are good to go. 
One of the ways would be create a custom block and display it on the home page.

Comment: thanks. programmatically everything is possible) can you give me some tips about custom block? i mean type of the block, widget etc?

Answer (score 0):

According to the **minimum** of information that you provided us, it's complicated to give you a precise answer but i try to give you an answer.

You say that the product is displayed in the **homepage** but we don't know how it is displayed ?, directly in the homepage, a block, a widget, block rendered via xml etc ...

**The way to follow:**

Try to search in the `cms_block`, `widget` if you find this block which displays this famous product, if you find it, look at how it's built, if there is the full code inside, so you have to add the piece of code below. if you just find the block link something like: `{{block class="path\to\block" name="some.name" template="Magento_Theme::html/file.phtml"}}` well you have to get this **phtml path** open it then you add the piece of code below.

You can also get help by enabling the **path hints** to find the phtml that displays this block.

The piece of code to display the product description:

```
<?php echo $_product->getDescription() ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
```

I hope I was pretty clear.